# mvc3 jquery trigger ajax actionlink on pageload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a button and each time it is clicked I simply want to increase the jquery variable **clickcount** by 1, however it is not working.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myajax').trigger('submit');
    });
</script>


<div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("hhh", "posts", "profile", new { id = @Model.poster.ID, page = 0 }, 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "postss", InsertionMode =  InsertionMode.Replace }, new {@id ="myajax" })
    <div id="postss"></div>
</div>
```

The trigger that I have in my jquery code does not seem to be firing up, any suggestions would be great.

Comment: You have not even shown a variable `clickcount` or how you increment it. And by _I have a button_, do you mean the the action link?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a link, not a form. Links don't have a `submit` event (a form does have a `submit` event) they have `click` event, so try to trigger `click` instead:

```
$('#myajax').trigger('click');
```